# Get next value of SEQUENCE using the ResultSet

Tags: java, sequence, derby

I have created a sequence using the following code:

```
String sqlCommand = "CREATE SEQUENCE TransactionIDs AS BIGINT START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 0 CYCLE";
Statement stmt = m_conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sqlCommand);
```

Now I want to get the next value from the sequence using following code:

```
String selectSql = "VALUES NEXT VALUE FOR TransactionIDs";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = m_DBConn.prepareStatement(selectSql); 
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
long transID = rs.getLong(1);
```

But on the `getLong()` line it throws the following exception:

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state - no current row.

What am I doing wrong with the `ResultSet`?

Comment: Call `ResultSet.next()` after you do the `executeQuery` and before you do the `getLong`.

Comment: @BryanPendleton That worked, thank you.